# Summing numbers (addition and subtract) from Div and drop Total to another Div with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am facing a problem in:
 Summing a total value, using `add` and `subtract` to get a total value with jQuery.

The project I am working on can be visited [here](https://agent007.prophiler.de/de/speisen).

Below the menu is a button named `Meine Bestellung`, that opens a slider.
If one clicks any `+` symbol on the right, name and price are added to the slider.

On the bottom a total value will be shown, that should change its value, when adding another line through hitting the `+` again or remove a line by clicking the `-` symbol from within the slider.

Somehow the calculation doesn't work as desired and so I am asking here for help.

It would be kind to receive some helpful feedback.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I am looking at your website right now and when I click the + buttons nothing happens; this is making it hard to understand your question. To help me understand, please be more specific about your question.

Comment: Lots of text, not really giving any information. Now we have to scour your site to find the appropriate files. Can you give the responsible code, the current problem and how it's suppose to work.

Comment: Could you add the relevant code to your question? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to produce a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Providing a link to something you are actively working on is next to useless. If you make changes as you try to fix things you then change the problem. Further more your question should still be relevant once the problem is solved. This is not the case with an active website.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unclear as to what your question is exactly, but for the time being this is the answer to "How can I add up the total price of all the items that are open (the + button has been clicked and the detail view has toggled open".

First, add a class that is toggled on the price when it is opened up (+ button clicked).

```
 $('.plus-button').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('item-selected');
 });
```

Then to calculate the total you could do something like:

```
 var total = 0;
 $('.price.item-selected').each(function() {
      total += parseInt(this.innerHTML); // You may have to format the string to look like a float (like remove any '$' or things like that)
 }
```